# Powershell script to create folders from list of names in a file

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, directory, copy-item

I have a text file that contains a list of files in different directories, e.g

- `C:\FolderOne\Testing.jpg`
- `C:\FolderTwo\Test.jpg`

I'd like to turn those names into folders. And if two files exist in one folder, e.g `FolderOne`, then both those files should go into the same folder.

I understand that the backslashes will also have to be replaced by underscores and the colon replaced by an underscore too.

Thus far, I'm able to get the contents from the file list and copy it into a specified folder. I would like to create a folder for each file in the file list, but the folder name needs to include `C_FolderOne` and `C_FolderTwo` and so on....

Any help would be appreciated!

What I have so far:

```
Param (
    [String]$model
)

# Debug line
$model = "DEV2";

[String]$drive = "C:";

#Go to the PG_dump directory
CD "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin"

##Execute PG_dump with no password
.\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file     "C:\Test\$date-DEV-$X.backup" "DEV"

#Get the content from the file list
$file_list = Get-Content "$drive\Testing\DEV33.txt" 
foreach ($file in $file_list)
{    
    Copy-Item  $file -Destination "C:\Testing"
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Could the paths being created under the "work" folder (e.g. - "C:\Testing") contain more than one segment (e.g. - C:\Folder A\Folder A - Sub Folder 0\...\filename.jpg")?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Basically, trying to create a folder for each file in the file list. The folder created should be named with the path to the folder e.g if a file called "Winter.jpg" is located at "C:\TestFolder\Winter.jpg" then a folder called C_TestFolder should be created.

Comment: @codemaker Hello, yes the paths being created under the "work" folder can contain more than one segment.

Comment: `(Split-Path -Path $Path -Parent) -replace ':\\','_'` @TheManBehindTheMan working out the logic to capture the rest of the `\\\`

Comment: @TheManBehindTheMan Easier way: `-replace '\W','_'` but this gives you a double underscore for C:\->__

Comment: This would be fairly easy to do with a [System.IO] reference in Powershell, but if you want a strictly Powershell routine, I'll leave that to @TheIncorrigible. :-) ...If you will consider using the .Net [System.IO] class library, let me know.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I did get to a point where i replaced both the colon and the underscore, i'm sure i can do that again. However, it's also important to notice that once these changes are made to the text file, i do not want to save the text file, i only want the backslash and colon to be changed for the purpose of creating a folder.

Comment: @codemaker Hello, strictly powershell is preferable. However, your .Net method is also welcome as this would be a learning opportunity for me.

Comment: If able, would you prefer to just recreate the folder structure of all the files and place such under your output folder (i.e. -  no need to use "_" in actual file name, just copy the file and it's full path without the drive letter to the output folder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method to do what you're asking.  It'll grab the parent path for the file and create the destination folder.

```
## Get the content from the file list.
foreach ($file in Get-Content -Path "$drive\Testing\DEV33.txt") {
    $name = (Split-Path -Path $file -Parent) -replace '\\', '_' -replace ':'
    New-Item -Path "path\to\$name" -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: I owe you chicken wings my friend or whatever you like lol. With some tweaking, it does exactly what i wanted it to do! Thanks very much.

Comment: @TheManBehindTheMan Great! Kindly upvote/mark as answer. What tweaks were necessary?

Comment: I had to add in an if statement so that if a folder doesn't exist that's when it should be created. And i have upvoted you, however, as i have a reputation less than 15 as i've only joined, i'am shown a message that says it has been recorded but will not change the publicly displayed score. Kind Regards.

Comment: @TheManBehindTheMan If you add `-Force` to `New-Item`, it'll automatically create the folder structure.